# Python: printing result of multiple inputs

Tags: python, loops, sum

I'm pretty new to python programming, but i'm trying to write a program that goes as follows:

First: the program asks the user for a fixed number.
Then: the user can input as many numbers as he wants, until he writes "stop".
(this is not really where i'm having trouble)

the output needs to be something like this:
'fixed number'
'input #1 = fixed number + first inputted number'
'input #2 = fixed number + first inputted number + second inputted
number'
'an so on until all inputted numbers have been added'

my code doesn't print this out correctly, it prints the correct #1, #2, #n
but not the summation i listed above.

Any help is appreciated

Here is my code at this moment:

```
random_number = int(input("Enter random number:"))
count_added = 0

while number != "stop":
    number = input("Enter number: ")

    if number == "stop":
        break
    else:
        number_int = int(number) 
        count_added += 1

    sum = number_int + random_number 

print(random_number)    

for x in range(1, count_added + 1): 
    print("input #{} is sum {} ".format(x, sum))
```

Comment: To clarify: say my random number is 10
input 1 = 10
input 2 = 15
input 3 = 20

the output should say (all on a different line)::
10
input #1 is 20
input #2 is 35
input #3 is 55

Comment: you can print it in `while` loop and then you don't need `for` loop. Or you have to keep numbers on list - now you keep only last value.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = []
sum = 0
while True:
    user_input = int(input('Enter the number'))
    if user_input != 'stop'
        input_list.append(user_input)
    elif user_input == 'stop':
        break;
for i in input_list:
    sum += i
print(sum)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
random_number = int(input("Enter random number:"))
number_list = [random_number]
flag = True

while flag:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter number: "))
        number_list.append(number)
    except:
        # if not a number, break the loop
        flag = False

print random_number

for i in range(1, len(number_list)):
    print "Input #%d is sum %d" \
            %(number_list[i], sum(number_list[:i+1]))
```